# Doctrine GROUP BY in a custom method - Symfony Repository

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I would like to group my query with Doctrine in Symfony3 in one of my repository but will not return any result. Mainly I think because of the attached relations to the entity.

the method looks as it follows

```
  public function findAllByCurrentDemands($ids) {
      $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('pt')
          ->select('pt')
          ->where('pt.id IN (:ids)')
          //->groupBy('pt.demand_id')
          ->setParameter('ids', $ids)
          ->getQuery()->getResult();

      dump($query);
      die;
  }
```

the raw sql example which is working in console and should be transformed to doctrine

```
SELECT demand_id
FROM ProductType
WHERE id IN (313,315,317,320,321,765,761,763,766)
GROUP BY demand_id;
```

How can I do this in a doctrine query like holding the attached relations?